# How to generate a random path in a 2d array Swift?

Tags: swift, path-finding

I have this issue and I don’t know how to solve it, I want create a random path in a 2d array NxN where I know only the start point and the end point. In this 2d array there are not obstacles, I want generate a path, I don’t care about the cost, but just the generated path between these two points. 
I tried to use GameplayKit to find it but I don’t know how because there are no graph, just this multidimensional array

- The rules are the following:

  - Diagonals are not allowed;
  - The path should not be self-crossing
  - [If the start point and the goal point are closest, the path must have at least one generated point, in this link of picture there is a
    little example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ucn.png)

I tried using the pathfinding of GameplayKit but with it returns an empty array, here is the code:

```
var nodes = [GKGridGraphNode]()

let maxSize = 3

//Here I'm filling the elements of the grid
for i in 0..<maxSize {
  for j in 0..<maxSize {

    let node = GKGridGraphNode(gridPosition: vector_int2(Int32(i), Int32(j)))
    nodes.append(node)
  }
}

let graph = GKGridGraph(nodes)
let start = GKGridGraphNode(gridPosition: vector_int2(0,0))
let end = GKGridGraphNode(gridPosition: vector_int2(2,2))

let path = graph.findPath(from: start, to: end) //It returns an empty array
print(path)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code. This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Also, what are your rules? Are diagonals allowed? Is the path allowed to be self-crossing?

Comment: - The rules are the following:
   - Diagonals are not allowed;
   - The path should not be self-crossing
   - If the start point and the goal point are closest, the path must have at least one generated point, in this link of picture there is a
   little example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ucn.png

Comment: Ofcourse I don't want a code-writing service, just a logic hint to accomplish this goal..

Comment: Well, you should at least tell us what you have tried that doesn't work. I suggest you start with a 2x2 - this is trivial, there are only two forms. Then you can generalise by partitioning the NxN into 4 areas, one of which includes the start and one of which includes the end. Then use your 2x2 solution...

Comment: I have removed the Swift tag as this clearly has nothing to do with Swift.

Comment: Ok, where to start? I mean that I want know if using the pathfinder of GameplayKit is a good way to do what I want. Exactly I'm trying to: create an array of nodes which are of type of [GKGridGraphNode], after that I start a for loop to create elements inside the array and then i start the pathfind giving as parameters the start and goal points, but after this step it returns an empty array. This is the code: https://pastebin.com/66QU7aHg